# Bounded Summation

Tags: sequences-and-series

Suppose we have non-negative sequences $\{a_k,b_k,c_k\}$ with :

(i) $\sum_k c_k = \infty.$

(ii) $\sup_k a_k = \infty$.

(iii) $|b_k| <b<\infty$.

Can we then conclude $\sum_k c_k (a_k -b_k) = \infty$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Take $b_k=0$ for all $k$, $c_k=\frac  1 k$ for $k$ even, $c_k=0$ for $k$ odd, $a_k=0$ for $k$ even $a_k=k$ for $k$ odd. We have $\sum c_k(a_k-b_k)=0$!

Comment: PS: If you want an example where $a_k,b_k,c_k$ are all strictly positive you can simply add $e^{-k}$ for each of $a_k,b_k,c_k$.